# Where to find World War 2 records for Canada?

Tags: military-records, world-war-2, canada, army

I was told a family story and I would like to see if there are any records to verify the story.

I was told that my grandfather began the military training for WW2 but just as he finished the military training, the war ended. He was 20 in 1945 and lived in Saskatchewan, Canada. He threw out his army tags when he was middle aged. I'm not sure if there would have been any associated records or where to find them.

Do such records exist for 'trainees'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Library and Archives Canada](https://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/military-heritage/second-world-war/Pages/introduction.aspx) hold Canadian military service records for World War 2; there will certainly be a record of your grandfather's enlistment and discharge -- armed forces the world over are extraordinarily keen on keeping records of their soldiers.

As he survived the war, his records are subject to access restrictions and not available online.  The restrictions and ways of requesting a copy are [here](https://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/transparency/atippr/Pages/Access-information-military-files.aspx#tab2a). In summary, you can apply in writing or via an online request form.

Note:

> For individuals still living: Personal information cannot be released without the written consent of the individual concerned.
>
> For individuals deceased less than 20 years: Limited personal
>   information will be released to an immediate family member (spouse,
>   parent, sibling, child or grandchild) of the individual concerned if
>   proof of relationship and proof of death are provided. Proof of death
>   is not required if the individual died while serving in the Canadian
>   Armed Forces.
>
> For individuals deceased more than 20 years: Personal information will
>   be released on an individual deceased for more than 20 years if proof
>   of death is provided. Proof of death is not required if the individual
>   died while serving in the Canadian Armed Forces.